# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Colorado River Data.csv'

Tags: python

```py
colo = pd.read_csv("Colorado River Data.csv")
colo.head()

colo = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\osaho\OneDrive\Desktop.csv")
colo.head()
```

they both do not work i keep getting the error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\osaho\\OneDrive\\Desktop.csv'
```

or

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Colorado River Data.csv'
```

also when I type
import os
os.getcwd()
I get '/home/user'
using cocalc jupyter notebook python 3 (system wide)

Comment: check if the name and location is correct

Comment: Can you show us your file tree?

Comment: Use 2 backslashes or 1 frontslash for your file location.

Comment: If my solution has answered your question, kindly mark it as accepted to close this off. If not, please post an update and I’ll do my best to assist

Answer (score 0):

With Python on Windows you need to double up the backslash in your path, as backslash is the Python escape character

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Python37'
```

So your file path actually needs to be **"C:\\Users\\osaho\\OneDrive\\Colorado River Data.csv"**

Comment: Where is the backslash?

Comment: @ProChess - what do you mean? My code demonstrates that Python uses double backslashes in paths on Windows, then I've answered the question?

Comment: @ProChess - Wiki Markup issue; I had two backslashes in my initial response, but had to edit to add a third